# Service @Transactional exception translation

Tags: web-services, cxf, aop, spring-transactions

I have a web service with an operation that looks like

```
public Result checkout(String id) throws LockException;
```

implemented as:

```
@Transactional
public Result checkout(String id) throws LockException {
    someDao.acquireLock(id); // ConstraintViolationException might be thrown on commit
    Data data = otherDao.find(id);
    return convert(data);
}
```

My problem is that locking can only fail on transaction commit which occurs outside of my service method so I have no opportunity to translate the `ConstraintViolationException` to my custom `LockException`.

#### Option 1

One option that's been suggested is to make the service delegate to another method that's @Transactional. E.g.

```
public Result checkout(String id) throws LockException {
    try {
        return someInternalService.checkout(id);
    }
    catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        throw new LockException();
    }
}

...

public class SomeInternalService {
    @Transactional
    public Result checkout(String id) {
        someDao.acquireLock(id);
        Data data = otherDao.find(id);
        return convert(data);
    }
}
```

My issues with this are:

- There is no reasonable name for the internal service that isn't already in use by the external service since they are essentially doing the same thing. This seems like an indicator of bad design.
- If I want to reuse someInternalService.checkout in another place, the contract for that is wrong because whatever uses it can get a ConstraintViolationException.

#### Option 2

I thought of maybe using AOP to put advice around the service that translates the exception. This seems wrong to me though because `checkout` needs to declare that it throws `LockException` for clients to use it, but the actual service will never throw this and it will instead be thrown by the advice. There's nothing to prevent someone in the future from removing `throws LockException` from the interface because it appear to be incorrect.

Also, this way is harder to test. I can't write a JUnit test that verifies an exception is thrown without creating a spring context and using AOP during the tests.

#### Option 3

Use manual transaction management in `checkout`? I don't really like this because everything else in the application is using the declarative style.

---

Does anyone know the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There's no one correct way.

A couple more options for you:

1. Make the DAO transactional - that's not great, but can work
2. Create a wrapping service - called Facade - whose job it is to do exception handling/wrapping around the transactional services you've mentioned - this is a clear separation of concerns and can share method names with the real lower-level service